# How do i use an IF statement in my procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

This is my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_ALL AS 
BEGIN
INSERT_INTO_P_ENZYME;
INSERT_INTO_P_EXPR_SYSTEM;
INSERT_INTO_P_BUFFER_SYSTEM;
INSERT_INTO_0_CONSTRUCT;
INSERT_INTO_1_PRODUCED;
INSERT_INTO_2_PURIFIED_ENZ;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  not_entered_purified) THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('test'); -- < -- a test line i want to see printed 
    show_what_failed_to_isnert_purified; -- < -- procedure i want to run
END INSERT_ALL;
/
```

I get this error:

```
19/5      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT_ALL" when expecting one of the following:     if 
Errors: check compiler log
```

The purpose of the IF is to select from a view that will show me all the records that didn't get inserted into the database during the previous procedure (i.e. when inserting into purified enz). The test print statement will be replaced by a procedure that gives me a list of just the rows that didn't get inserted. Why don't I just create a badfile and do this in a less dumb way, you might ask? Because that doesn't tell me which records got rejected because they didn't match the criteria I set with joins.

Trying with `END IF`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_ALL AS 
BEGIN
INSERT_INTO_P_ENZYME;
INSERT_INTO_P_EXPR_SYSTEM;
INSERT_INTO_P_BUFFER_SYSTEM;
INSERT_INTO_0_CONSTRUCT;
INSERT_INTO_1_PRODUCED;
INSERT_INTO_2_PURIFIED_ENZ;
IF (SELECT * FROM  insert_2_purified_enz ) THEN
    SAY_HI;
END IF;
END INSERT_ALL;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SAY_HI AS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('test');
END SAY_HI;
/
```

Error:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
9/5       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternat
9/44      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:     ) , and or 
Errors: check compiler log
```

Comment: `if exists` is not valid syntax. There is no `exists` keyword in PL/SQL other than in SQL statements. There's also no `if (select)`. There are examples of PL/SQL syntax in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/index.html) and online so you don't need to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Counting records in a view wasn't working, so I just made a variable for the row count.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_INTO_2 AS
    not_entered NUMBER;
    
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO not_entered FROM not_entered_purified;
    INSERT 
    INTO purified_enz 
        (
        produced_id,
        p_batch,
        yield) 
    SELECT  
        produced_id,
        p_batch,    
        yield
    FROM insert_2
    LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

    IF not_entered > 1 THEN
        show_what_failed_to_isnert_purified;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( (not_entered) ||' Records failed to be inserted. 
        They are either duplicates or referencing missing entries.' );
    END IF;
END INSERT_INTO_2;
/
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a try to pull (front slash) at the end like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_ALL AS 
BEGIN
INSERT_INTO_P_ENZYME;
INSERT_INTO_P_EXPR_SYSTEM;
INSERT_INTO_P_BUFFER_SYSTEM;
INSERT_INTO_0_CONSTRUCT;
INSERT_INTO_1_PRODUCED;
INSERT_INTO_2_PURIFIED_ENZ;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  not_entered_purified) THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('test'); -- < -- a test line i want to see printed 
    show_what_failed_to_isnert_purified; -- < -- procedure i want to run
END IF;
INSERT_INTO_3_CHAR_ABTS;
INSERT_INTO_4_CHAR_LYPO;
INSERT_INTO_5_CHAR_DSF;
INSERT_INTO_6_CELL_LOCAL;
INSERT_INTO_7_CELL_TOX; 
INSERT_INTO_8_CELL_EFFICACY;
INSERT_INTO_9_RAT_TOX;
INSERT_INTO_10_MOUSE_EFFICACY;
END INSERT_ALL\;
```

reference: https://kb.informatica.com/solution/3/Pages/14954.aspx

Comment: I tried this and it still gave me the same error as the one I posted at the bottom of my question.

Comment: "front slash" isn't a thing. There is forward slash `/` and backslash \. Neither are part of PL/SQL syntax.